# Send list of recently viewed products in contact form email in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I want to include the list of Recently Viewed Products for the Visitor in the Contact Email sent by the Contact Form. I know how to modify the Email Template as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Product URLs"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.product_urls}}</td>
</tr>
```

I can display the Recently Viewed Products Widget on the Contact Form by adding this code to my theme contact_index_index.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" name="recently_viewed_products" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
            <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
            <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price,learn_more</argument>
            <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I think this is an alternative using the old widget:

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
    <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
        <action method="setPageSize">
            <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

But how do I submit the product list when we post the Contact Form?

I only need to include a list of Product ID, SKU, Name or URL.

Update:
I am making progress.
In my theme I override Magento_Reports/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml
So now I can extract the required data like this:

```
$product_urls = '';
$product_ids = '';
$product_skus = '';
```

Then immediately after the "foreach" statement:

```
<?php
    if ($iterator > 1) {
        $product_urls .= ',';
        $product_ids .= ',';
        $product_skus .= ',';
    }
    $product_urls .= $block->getProductUrl($_item);
    $product_ids .= $_item->getId();
    $product_skus .= $_item->getSku();
?>
```

This gives me comma separated lists. Now I will add hidden  controls to submit the data with the form...

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I found a trivial way to solve the entire problem with a single line of code using Magento Admin:

1) Go to Magento Admin, Marketing, Email Templates

2) Add New Template

3) Load Contact Form Template

4) Template Name = "My Contact Form"

5) Add the following code to Template Content:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Reports\\Block\\Product\\Widget\\Viewed" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}
```

6) Save Template

7) Go to Magento Admin, Stores, Configuration, General, Contacts, Email Options

8) Email Template = "My Contact Form"

Crude but effective!